# How to schedule asp.net app to start at given time

Tags: asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I need my asp.net app to start let say every day at 23h. How to do this on windows server 2008?

Comment: @admdrew I asked a question on Q&A site.

Comment: As written, this post would be off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Web apps are request-driven by design - how do you "start" a web site without a client request?

Answer (score 1):

Websites are designed to respond to client requests, so one solution would be to create an app that generates the proper client request, then schedule that to run when you need it to.

Another option is to move the *process* (read: code) that needs to run at a certain time into a separate library that is shared by the web site and a console app, then schedule the console app to run at a given time.